# Can't append value to my NSArray variable

Tags: swift, nsarray

I have a NSArray and i need to append some values but **array.append** doesn't seems to works on a NSArray. What can i use to append something on a NSArray like a normal array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add or append element in `NSArray` as `NSArray` is immutable.For this you need to take `NSMutableArray`